# How did the Doctor get Captain Janeway and Tom Paris back to human in "Threshold"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

They are seen as lizard creatures, then they are stunned with a phaser, brought back aboard *Voyager*, and seen next in human form back in sick bay.  How did the Doctor do this?

Comment: Using the power of awful writing

Comment: Ah, yes, the episode where they changed into lizards, mated, had offspring and then became humans again. [The one the writers would sooner forget](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Threshold_(episode)#Background_information).

Comment: If I recall correctly, they are transformed back *during the commercial break*. That was the last episode of Star Trek I ever watched. I sincerely hope it improved.

Comment: I was going to say they reversed the polarity of deflector array..... But I suppose they just reversed the polarity of the proton ray. That's almost the same thing.....

Comment: I was fortunate to have had forgotten about this episode. Thanks, Darren.

Comment: The episode was de-canonized before it even ended, restoring Janeway and Paris to their former selves.

Comment: For almost thirty years many thought that *Spock's Brain* was the worst Star Trek episode that could possibly be created. They were wrong. So very wrong...

Comment: @EricLippert I'm sorry that your patience didn't hold out.  Later episodes were better.  I believe this episode is widely recognized as the worst.  [Wikipedia's article on the episode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threshold_%28Star_Trek:_Voyager%29) shows the writer (Brannon Braga) of the episode called it "a royal, steaming stinker" (apparently ultimately quoting directly from an interview which is included in the DVD box set).  [Wikis's answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/121144/50747) quotes Braga further.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The Doctor used anti-proton therapy to [erase all traces of the mutated DNA](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/212.htm) from their system.

> **EMH**: *I believe the answer lies in forcing his DNA to revert to its original coding. Once that occurs, his body should return to its former state.*
>
> **CHAKOTAY:** *How do we do that?*
>
> **EMH**: *We destroy all of the new DNA in his body. His cells will have to use the original coding as a blueprint. But the only way to destroy the mutant DNA is with highly focused antiproton radiation.*

*Later*

> **EMH:** *I've eradicated all traces of the mutant DNA from your system and restored your original genome. Congratulations. You're human again.*

Unfortunately the same treatment won't erase all memory of this episode from my brain.

Comment: You can purchase a [Tom Paris "Threshold" action figure](http://www.startrek.com/uploads/assets/articles/In5.jpg). It comes with "three mutant offspring".

Comment: @Praxis incredible!

Comment: @Praxis"Warning! Chocking hazard". I know I nearly did.

Comment: @Praxis -- I love the way the price on the toy was cut from $7.99 to 3 for $10.   That kind of says it all.

Comment: @Praxis Wow. I shudder at how ridiculous this toy is. I bet it was a real hit.

Answer (score 14):

In universe, from [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Threshold_(episode)#Act_Five)

> Paris and Janeway are reverted back to their Human selves **using The Doctor's anti-proton treatments**, although Paris is extremely embarrassed about having mated with the captain.

ie it was magic.

Out of universe, it was a sordid assault on rational thinking by a writing staff who should have known better<sup>1</sup>. From [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Threshold_(episode)#Background_information) again:

> Brannon Braga named this episode as the one installment from the entirety of Voyager that he would "just as soon forget" and remarked, "That's a real low point [....] It really backfired on me. It was poorly executed by me."

<sub>1 And, to be fair, they did do *much* better for the rest of Voyager's seven seasons.</sub>

Comment: Magic. Otherwise known as **deus ex machina** _noun_ an unexpected power or event saving a seemingly hopeless situation, especially as a contrived plot device in a play or novel.

Comment: "And, to be fair, they did do much better for the rest of Voyager's seven seasons." Which isn't saying much when it is literally impossible to do worse. :(

Comment: What was the reasoning for even entertaining such a horrible plot and then going forward with the week's worth of shooting to turn it into an actual episode?!  Isn't there a point where you look at it and call a time out?

Comment: @enorl76 That's a great idea, except that it would have disrupted the shooting schedule for the *next* episode. I do wonder, though, how many people this particular train wreck had to get past to find a green light... how many people *didn't* think it was stupid.